# I am trying to create an empty list in python, but for some reason there is a difference in the two methods

Tags: python, list, loops

What is the difference between these two methods in python? Shouldn't the outcome for list2 be exactly the same?

Method 1:

```
list2= [[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]
```

Method 2:

```
list1 = [[], [], []]
list2 = []
for i in range(5):
    list2_task.append(list1)
```

Comment: In the second case you append the **same** list many times

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html